# incorrect sum of a numeric datatype- interbase

Tags: sql, interbase

I want to get the total of many integer using `sum()`, but the output is wrong.

this are the amounts that i have

2352, 2368, 400, 500, 500, 1831.29, 110, 518.8, 1842.5, 205.55, 284.4, 2368.93
4570, 26.9, 110, 2515, 2050, 180, 385, 280, 280, 972, 1352, 600, 125

when i use calculator, its total is 26,727.37, 
but when i use this code

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNTDUE)
FROM TABLE
```

it sums 26,727.36, which is wrong.
what to do to get the correct answer?
by the way its datatype is numeric(15,2)

Comment: Odd. My dbms returns 26727.37.

Comment: Are you sure those values above are the values actually stored in the table? Did you insert using host-variables/parameters, or using literals?

Comment: Are you using Firebird or InterBase? Don't tag both, they are not the same database. Also, values like `284.4` are not integers.

Comment: when storing it uses numeric (15,2), i think it has some decimals hidden that's why i can't get the exact output . by the way it's interbase . sorry

Comment: that's host viarables

Comment: Perhaps it can be different w.r.t. SQL Dialect. One perhaps should check what was underlying data type. Probably usual rounding error.

Comment: i tried removing one amount and saw that the problem was this amount 2368.93. when i don't include that amount the total would be correct but when i include it the total is 0.01 less than the correct amount. what do you think is the reason?